# Need filtering example on Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and have a requirement like the below

1. A screen shows all the employees starting with particular name pattern (the default is all)
2. a checkbox to filter out only active employees( the employees who are still on company payroll)

The team follows getting the relevant data from service code meaning

1. when all employees should be shown, the service code gets the required data from db and sends the data to UI component
2. when only active employees should be shown, the service should filter out inactive data (through direct db query or after fetching of data) and send it to UI component

Basically the UI component is not involved with any filtering of data.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it by adding the following

1. component.html

> ```
> <div class="form-check">
> <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="showActive" (change)="fieldChange($event)"/>
> <label class="form-check-label" for="showActive"> Show Active</label>
> </div>
> ```

2. component.ts

> export class EmployeeDisplayComponent {
> isChecked=false;
> fieldsChange(evt) {
> this.isChecked=evt.target.checked;
> // make service call to get the data }
> }